# how to type connect in the absence of mapDispatchToProps

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I have the following setup:

```
@types/react@16.9.41
@types/react-redux@7.1.9
react@16.13.1
react-redux@7.2.0
```

The below code typechecks with the strictest possible settings:

```
import React, {Dispatch} from 'react';
import { connect, ConnectedProps } from 'react-redux';

type RootState = {
  age: number
};

type MapStateToProps = {
  age: number
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: RootState): MapStateToProps => {
  return {
    age: state.age
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch<any>) => {
  return {dispatch}
}

const connector = connect<MapStateToProps, {dispatch: Dispatch<any>}, {}, RootState>(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps);
type PropsFromRedux = ConnectedProps<typeof connector>;
type Props =  PropsFromRedux & {children?: React.ReactNode};



const Test = ({age}: Props) => {
  return (
    <>
      age is {age}
    </>
  );
}
export default connector(Test);
```

However, I am forced to supply a dummy `mapDispatchToProps` and its type. I can also do the following and it typechecks also:

```
const connector = connect<MapStateToProps, {dispatch: Dispatch<any>}, {}, RootState>(mapStateToProps);
```

However, I don't want to have to supply by hand the type for the return object of the default `mapDispatchToProps`. Is this defined anywhere? Or is there a more idiomatic way to do this?
Weirdly, I've also noticed that if I use the following syntax:

```
const connector = connect<MapStateToProps, {dispatch: Dispatch<any>}, {}, RootState>(mapStateToProps, undefined);
```

... then that fails to typecheck:

```
TS2769: No overload matches this call.
Overload 1 of 15, '(mapStateToProps: MapStateToPropsParam<MapStateToProps, {}, RootState>, mapDispatchToProps: MapDispatchToPropsNonObject<{ dispatch: Dispatch<any>; }, {}>): InferableComponentEnhancerWithProps<...>', gave the following error.
Argument of type 'undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MapDispatchToPropsNonObject<{ dispatch: Dispatch<any>; }, {}>'.
Overload 2 of 15, '(mapStateToProps: MapStateToPropsParam<MapStateToProps, {}, RootState>, mapDispatchToProps: MapDispatchToPropsParam<{ dispatch: Dispatch<any>; }, {}>): InferableComponentEnhancerWithProps<...>', gave the following error.
Argument of type 'undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MapDispatchToPropsParam<{ dispatch: Dispatch<any>; }, {}>'.
```

... which seems pretty weird cause if you call a function with fewer arguments then the remaining ones get `undefined` so I don't see what's the difference between the following two calls and why the first one typechecks but not the second:

```
const connector = connect<MapStateToProps, {dispatch: Dispatch<any>}, {}, RootState>(mapStateToProps);

const connector = connect<MapStateToProps, {dispatch: Dispatch<any>}, {}, RootState>(mapStateToProps, undefined);
```

Comment: So you say that this `const connector = connect<MapStateToProps>(mapStateToProps);` does not work for you?

Comment: @Rostyslav no, it doesn't type check

Comment: Replace `connect` with `useSelector` and `useDispatch` hooks. Legacy interface of `react-redux` is hard to type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have to write a `mapDispatch` in that situation at all - `connect` already passes `dispatch` as a prop when you don't pass a `mapDispatch` argument.

Second, per [the React-Redux "Static Typing" docs page](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/static-typing#inferring-the-connected-props-automatically), you shouldn't need to add any generic arguments to `connect` - they will be inferred.

Third, you also don't have to declare a return type for `mapState`, as that will be inferred as well.

So, this *should* be all you need:

```
import React, {Dispatch} from 'react';
import { connect, ConnectedProps } from 'react-redux';

type RootState = {
  age: number
};


const mapStateToProps = (state: RootState) => {
  return {
    age: state.age
  };
};

const connector = connect(mapStateToProps);
type PropsFromRedux = ConnectedProps<typeof connector>;
type Props =  PropsFromRedux & {children?: React.ReactNode};

const Test = ({age}: Props) => {
  return (
    <>
      age is {age}
    </>
  );
}
export default connector(Test);
```